# webmethod not working in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using the below code to call a c# function.But its working fine in aspx page not in 
user control.Please help me to solve this issue.

```
function add_plan() {
            try {
                alert('enter');
                PageMethods.add_plan_Items(onSucceeded, onFailed);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert(ex);
            }

        }

        function CallParametersPageMethod() {
            try {
                PageMethods.MyFirstParameterPageMethod("This is a Demo", onSucceeded, onFailed);
            }
            catch (ex) {
                alert(ex);
            }
        }
        function onSucceeded(result, userContext, methodName) {
            $get('div1').innerHTML = result;
        }

        function onFailed(error, userContext, methodName) {
            alert("An error occurred")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the method from the control's code behind file (`ascx.cs`) to the page's code behind file (`.aspx.cs`). Or move the method in a web service.